# Angular start session for login system front-end

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, session-cookies

I am building a small Angular and Node app. I have a form that a user inserts a email, then gets sent to the Node back-end, providing the credentials prove correct a 200 response code is passes to the Angular side. I now want to start a session if 200 response and set a variable to true to use on front-end to enable a div to use ng-hide or ng-show (will hold a button eventually).

**So in summary**

If 200 response generate a session or cookie and also set a var to true to enable ng-show or ng-hide.

**Question**

1. I am generation a variable that i am passing to the scope

   $scope.LoginCorrect = true;

However my html side I have 2 div's that should respond depending on the scope variable `LoginCorrect` but are not responding ... so first question is why ?

2. Am I generating the cookie correct ?

**Angular controller**

This is where I set the variable and the cookie if 200 response code

```
 FirstModule.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.LoginForm = function () {
        var data = {
            LoginEmail: $scope.sometext.LoginEmail
        };

        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/back-end/controller',
            method: "POST",
            data: data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 200)
                $scope.sometext = "You are a valid member, please proceed to Mock Up Maker";
            $cookies.put(data); // set cookie
            $scope.LoginCorrect = true; // set variable to true for use in ng-show

        }).catch(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 400)
                $scope.sometext = "Hmm, it seems you are not registered, try again or register";
            else if (response.status === 404)
                $scope.sometext = "this is non a valid email address, please check email";
            else if (response.status === 500)
                $scope.sometext = "No API connection. Server side fail ";

            else $scope.sometext = "Server connection error, give it a second to establish connection then try again";
        });
    }
});
```

**Angular view**

Here I have ng-hide and ng-show divs that are not responding on the var passed to the scope

```
<form class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2"
      ng-controller="LoginController"
      ng-submit="LoginForm()">
    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email*</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control col-sm-12" name="LoginEmail" placeholder="Enter valid E-mail"
                   ng-model="sometext.LoginEmail">
            <p>{{ sometext }}</p>
        </div>
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
</form>

<div ng-hide="LoginCorrect">
    hide when logged in
</div>

<div ng-show="LoginCorrect">
   show when signed in
</div>
```

Comment: Can't see that you injected `$cookies` module to your controller ?

Comment: TBH i may have not, first time trying cookies in Angular

Comment: Okay do you getting any errors in console ? AngularJS uses the dependency injection - so each dependency need to be injected to be used in specific controller.

Comment: Hmm good point, only dev tool console error is $cookies is not defined

Comment: So inject it here `FirstModule.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $http, $cookies) { // ... }`

Comment: thanks, am trying atm

Comment: Hmm im getting `angular.js:9778 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=ookiesProvider%20%3C-%20%24cookies`  would I need to include ngCookies in my module ?